# Objective-C How to run the same code for different variables

Tags: objective-c

Im reasonably new to coding and I'm looking for a way to have the same code run but each time for separate variable names.

Basically I have multiple variables each needing to run the same code. but due to the way I intend the app to work i don't want to have to copy and paste the code over and over and change out variable names since this makes my code untidy and if I want to make a change further down the line i don't want to have to edit 100s of lines of code per variable.

Example:

```
   if (Variable1 == 1{
       Object1.center.x = CGPointMake(AnotherObject1.center.x, AnotherObject1.center.y);
       Random1.hidden = NO; 
       [More code here just don't need to type this out to explain my purpose]
   }
   if (Variable2 == 1{
       Object2.center.x = CGPointMake(AnotherObject2.center.x, AnotherObject2.center.y);
       Random2.hidden = NO; 
       [More code here just don't need to type this out to explain my purpose]
   }
   if (Variable3 == 1{
       Object3.center.x = CGPointMake(AnotherObject3.center.x, AnotherObject3.center.y);
       Random3.hidden = NO; 
       [More code here just don't need to type this out to explain my purpose]
   }
```

And i need maybe 20 of these if statements you say all pretty much running the same code but with different variables involved (In my code instead of if statements they can be anything from IBactions to Collisions. Im just trying to use a global example.

I basically need to shorten this down. I'm happy to have repeated statements assuming they won't get in the way if i need to change something that effects the main statements.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: All you need to do is code up an internal procedure and run it with SOAP (Symbolic Optimizing Assembler Program).  Of course, the only system that can run that is probably in the Smithsonian, and I don't think SOAP recognizes Objective-C syntax anyway.

Comment: (Or you could write a method to implement the logic and call it multiple times.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a method with an argument.

```
-(void)methodName:(typeOfYourVariable)variable
{
here, write the code you want to apply to each variable.
}
```

and call this method by doing this

```
[self methodName:variable1];
[self methodName:variable2];
[self methodName:variable3];
```

etc...

Here is an exemple

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    int variable1 = 10;
    int variable2 = 15;
    int variable3 = 40;

    [self calculateSquare:variable1];
    [self calculateSquare:variable2];
    [self calculateSquare:variable3];

}

-(void)calculateSquare:(int)number
{
    NSLog(@"%i^2 = %i", number, number*number);
}
```

And here is the result in console :

```
2014-11-29 00:30:49.743 Test a jeter[10134:418660] 10^2 = 100
2014-11-29 00:30:49.743 Test a jeter[10134:418660] 15^2 = 225
2014-11-29 00:30:49.743 Test a jeter[10134:418660] 40^2 = 1600
```

If you want to use multiple arguments :

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    int variable1 = 10;
    int variable2 = 15;
    int variable3 = 40;

    [self addNumber:variable1 andNumber:variable2];
    [self addNumber:variable1 andNumber:variable3];
    [self addNumber:variable2 andNumber:variable3];

}

-(void)addNumber:(int)number1 andNumber:(int)number2
{
    NSLog(@"%i+%i = %i", number1, number2, number1 + number2);
}
```

And here is the result :

```
2014-11-29 09:54:04.470 Test a jeter[10395:466552] 10+15 = 25
2014-11-29 09:54:04.471 Test a jeter[10395:466552] 10+40 = 50
2014-11-29 09:54:04.471 Test a jeter[10395:466552] 15+40 = 55
```

Of course, you can use as many arguments as you want, two or more :) You're not obliged to use arguments of the same type. You can do what you want ^^

Comment: Thanks +Atomnium just a quick question, how can i use multiple variable changes in the method (so not only the variable i selected changes i also need 2 or 3 other variables to change as well)

Comment: You want to use more than one argument? 
I'll edit my answer ;)

Comment: Thanks! the only problem i have is that none of my booleans update with this method and i cannot work out why. i state them in the method name with andBOOL:(BOOL)BoolenNameHere @Atomnium